# how to update a json file in react-native expo

Tags: react-native, expo

Unable to use react-native-fs. Getting error as
"Error: Requiring module "node_modules/react-native-fs/FS.common.js", which threw an exception: Invariant Violation: Native module cannot be null"

This is how i just imported .

`const RNFS = require('react-native-fs');`